# How would you create a single object effect with ecs like a shadow moving straight and a bouncing ball?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, entity-system, particles

I have a bullet that has projectile motion, this bullet is also an effect. Also the bullet has a shadow, that fade on specific time relatively  to bullet. So I'm thinking of using the libgdx particle system (I am using an Entity Component-based System approach) so I created a particle component, or would you rather recommend to create another component for that specific effect? like a projectile component and linear component or a motion component in general.

Creating shadow, bullet, and other single object effect entity. Notice that I doesn't use any Box2d Physics yet.

```
Entity shadow = engine.createEntity();

... add texture, transform, movement or with gravity components

engine.addEntity(shadow);
```

To move the shadow entity

```
// Shadow
Vector2 linear = ...
movement.velocity.set(linear);
```

To move the bullet entity

```
// Bullet
gravity.vertical = 9.8f; // set earth gravity
Vector2 projectile = ...
movement.velocity.set(projectile);
// Also I need to calculate the time to reach its destination to add in lifespan
```

To create and move a ball entity

```
Entity ball = ...

// assume that the world has zero horizontal and 9.8 vertical Vector2 gravity 
// set the physics body and set restitution to have bounce
physics.body = createCircleBody(...); 

add(texture);
add(transform);
add(physics);
```

Every single object has lifespan so I added some lifespan component

```
LifespanComponent lifespan = ...
lifespan.duration = 0.5f; // let say half a second
```

Then the lifespan system will handle if the time reached the duration, then remove entity.

The problem is, Because `Particle System` has many moving objects, I don't know if I could use libgdx Particle System to create a single moving object that has a lifespan, like shadow, ball, bullet.

Comment: Can u give some examples for what you've done

Comment: @GioraGuttsait hey please check above, I updated and added some examples on how do I create and move entity

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean in `this bullet it also an effect`? and what's exactly not working for you?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait it means, It doesn't have any physics body.

Comment: Okay, I get it. So what about what you're trying to do? I don't exactly understand your problem?

Comment: for me the problem is, libgdx has already a particle system. I don't know If I could use this system to create those effect or just stick to my idea.

Comment: because suddenly, my idea and a particle almost has same behaviors, it acts like a particle and have a lifespan. But mine only has one object while a particle has one or more object

Comment: Why not create a component that wraps the libgdx particle system?
This is what I'm trying to do with Farseer. I'm trying to add a component that uses the Farseer physics engine, that would contain whatever logic needed, and I would create a system to manage those components, and this way everything stays decoupled.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait maybe my question is wrong, I should create a new question. Anyways have you tried creating a single object with particle system?